# vb.net add one week to a given date

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I am trying to add one week to a given date using an extension method
and then retrieve the date of the first day in the week (of the date returned from the AddWeeks function)

```
Private Sub doSomething()
  Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddWeeks(1)

  dt = dt.StartOfWeek(dt.DayOfWeek) ' The year returned here is 0001
End Sub

<Extension()>
    Public Function AddWeeks(ByVal dt As DateTime, numOfWeeks As Integer) As 
    DateTime
        Return dt.AddDays(numOfWeeks * 7)
End Function
<Extension()>



    <Extension()>
Public Function StartOfWeek(ByVal dt As DateTime, start As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Dim diff As Integer = dt.DayOfWeek - start
    If (diff < 0) Then
        diff += 7
    End If

    Return dt.AddDays(-diff)
End Function
```

The problem with this code is that the date returned is is with wrong year, it is always like `dd/mm/0001`

Comment: I've just tried your code and it does not return the year as `0001`. It does not work as it should because the `StartOfWeek` method is wrong, but nothing to do with the date returning as `dd/mm/0001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the first day of the week try deducting a day until you get to Monday like this:

```
Public Function StartOfWeek(ByVal dt As DateTime, start As DayOfWeek) As DateTime

    If Not dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then

        While dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Monday

            dt = dt.AddDays(-1)

        End While

    End If

    Return dt

End Fuction
```